# Flutter Layout: Space between to flex inside container with box constraints

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is one I have been having problems with. Box constraints on a container stop the space between from flexing on a row/column.

```
 Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 1080, minWidth: 450),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 75,
        width: 150,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 75,
        width: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

How do I get the space between to flex until minwidth is met?

Comment: having main axis size = min on the row doesn't work?

Comment: Nope. Same issue

Comment: whats your parent containers actual width when you run? Children containers have a total width of 450 right?

Comment: Parent's width is screen width set by media query

Comment: The parent is a row with mainaxis center. I think this the issue. If I swap the parent out for a Center widget, it seems to work. Doing more testing.

Comment: That's what it was. Row as a parent was causing the issue.

Comment: yeah center would make more sense. Would be easier to identify the problem if you post your rest of the code